# bean function does not return full map of properties

Tags: user-interface, clojure, javabeans, awt

Keep on crawling on Clojure and now with Java GUI.
How can I get the map of properties for GridBagConstrains?
The `bean` function does'n return the full map with `:gridx, :gridy, :fill` and so on ...

```
user=> (import '(java.awt GridBagConstraints))
java.awt.GridBagConstraints
user=> (def gbc (GridBagConstraints.))
#'user/gbc
user=> (bean gbc)
{:class java.awt.GridBagConstraints}
```

As always thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose, it happens because `(bean)` function uses [JavaBean conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean). It means that for every property you should have getter and setter, so in GridBagConstraint we don't have getters for values that you need.

You can get and set specific properties without getters by simple point-access to them:

```
user> (. gbc gridx)
-1
user> (set! (. gbc gridx 10))
10
```

Comment: Just a small note. Only getters are needed for the `bean` function to work.

Comment: Thanks amalloy. I guess I have to give a deep look to the JavaBean conventions rules to be able to identify the classes where (bean) can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer from mishadoff says GridBagConstraints doesn't have getters. It uses direct access to the property fields, so it isn't properly "beanable".

It is possible to discover the property fields using java introspection via direct java interop.

```
(doseq [f (.. gbc (getClass) (getFields))] 
   (println (.getName f)))
```

---

### Extended answer

The following will use reflection to build a map of fieldname, fieldvalue pairs after filtering out the "magic numbers" declared as static final:

```
(defn lookup-fields [obj]
 (letfn [(isStaticFinal [field]
       (let [mods (.getModifiers field)]
         (and (java.lang.reflect.Modifier/isStatic mods)
              (java.lang.reflect.Modifier/isFinal mods))))]
    (into {}
      (for [f (.. obj (getClass) (getFields)) 
              :when ((complement isStaticFinal) f)]
        [(keyword (.getName f)) (.get f obj)]))))


user=> (lookup-fields gbc)
{:gridx -1, :gridwidth 1, :ipadx 0, :ipady 0, :anchor 10,
 :weighty 0.0, :gridheight 1, :weightx 0.0, :fill 0, 
 :insets #Insets java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0], 
 :gridy -1}
```

Comment: OK Alex I see that there is another way to get to the properties and methods. I tried, but does not return values. Is it possible to get them anyhow? Thanks.

Comment: @logigolf - sorry I wasn't meaning to be obscure. My initial answer was intended to go with mishadoff's providing an interactive way to get the names to be used with direct field access. I have extended my answer to give a more complete usage of reflection to extract the fields and the values.

Comment: Thank you again Alex. I had a little time to work on the subject today and I was going on the same direction before I saw your extended answer. Thanks again, that helps me a lot on this continue effort to learn Clojure and the Java interop.